# Image boundary after rotation

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, julia

I am trying to find keypoints in a rotated and then subsampled image using fastcorners. My code:

```
tfm = Translation((r/2)-1,(c/2)-1) ∘ LinearMap(RotMatrix(-theta)) ∘ Translation(-((r/2)-1),-((c/2)-1))
uR = warp(img1, inv(tfm), indices(img1))
uT = subSample(uR, axes(uF)[1][1], axes(uF)[1][end], t) 
kpts = Keypoints(fastcorners(uT, 12, 0.5))
```

> subsampling in vertical direction. So resultant image is no longer a
>   rectangle but a parallelogram

Now I want to remove keypoints at the boundary of the rotated and subsampled image(i.e. something like d distance from the boundary of the distorted image, parallelogram). 
Can you guys suggest something how I can proceed? kpts is storing the cartesian coordinates of the keypoints in the distorted image.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the distance to each of the corners of the distorted image from the coordinates of the feature point using the formula mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248617/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment). Then find the coordinates of the keypoint in the original image by upsampling and then performing an inverse rotation.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the keypoints, transform them with the inverse transformation (including the inverse subsampling) and then check if they are on the boundary of the original image.